# How to replace multiple values in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have some of this Code:

```
function writeIslamicDate(adjustment) {
    var wdNames = new Array("Ahad","Ithnin","Thulatha","Arbaa","Khams","Jumuah","Sabt");

    var iMonthNames = new Array("Muharram","Safar","Rabi'ul Awwal","Rabi'ul Akhir",
    "Jumadal Ula","Jumadal Akhira","Rajab","Sha'ban",
    "Ramadan","Shawwal","Dhul Qa'ada","Dhul Hijja");

    var iDate = kuwaiticalendar(adjustment);
    var outputIslamicDate = wdNames[iDate[4]] + ", " + (iDate[5]-1) + " " + iMonthNames[iDate[6]] + " " + iDate[7] + " AH";
    return outputIslamicDate;
}
document.write(writeIslamicDate());
```

---

Output : Ithnin, 23 Ramadan 1435 AH

?

I want to replace 23 with bengali number ২,৩ ///// or two, three 
I watch and try a lot of but couldn't success.. Is there are any to solve this ?
Thanks.
I do like

```
var someString = (iDate[5]-1) + " " + iMonthNames[iDate[6]] + " " + iDate[7] + " হিজরী";
var outputIslamicDate = somestring.replace(/1/g, "১").replace(/4/g, "৪");
return outputIslamicDate;
```

but it's not work...

Comment: You need to replace keyboard before you continue working.

Comment: Where did u write function to convert From 1 Language to other?

Comment: what is This ?? unwanted closing bracket???? Where is opening then ?? what is kuwaiticalendar() ? is this function custom made or plugin?

Comment: now look at the post there is code,, first time i forget !!!

Answer (score 0):

Use regex and the global flag:

`str.replace(/word/g, 'word2');`

Comment: i need to do multiple replace than how i could write ?